# VMware Workstation would not apply changes to settings

Tags: vmware-workstation

Whenever I try to change ANY setting through VM > settings, changes I make simply don't apply. Specifically I've tried to change USB compatibility from default 3.0 to 2.0, but after I press OK button, setting go back to what they before. It seems like a very strange problem to me, because after a day of researching, I haven't come across any similar problems. To clarify: settings are not grayed out or anything, and changing them doesn't produce any error or whatsoever.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: How are you making these changes to the configuration be as specific as possible

Comment: What OS are you using? What version of VMware Workstation are you using? Immediately after this happens, do you see any relevant failure messages in the UI log (its location should be displayed in the Help > About dialog)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem by creating fresh copy of virtual OS X and selecting USB 2.0 compatibility before first launch of virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to run your VMWare as Administrator.
- Check and correct the access permissions to your VM folder.
- Try to run all VMWARE services with maximal permissions.
  (VMAuthdService, VMnetDHCP, "VMware NAT Service", VMUSBArbServiceVMwareHostd).
- Try to manually change needed options in configuration file and see, will the program overwrite them or not.